# How to make pytest select tests having markers with arguments

Tags: python, pytest

[According to the official documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/example/markers.html#passing-a-callable-to-custom-markers), it is possible to mark tests with custom markers that have positional or keyword arguments. For instance:

```py
@pytest.mark.my_marker.with_args('this')
def test_marker_this():
    pass

@pytest.mark.my_marker.with_args('that')
def test_marker_that():
    pass
```

From the command line, how do I select the test(s) where `my_marker` has the argument `this`?

The only approach I could think of (`pytest -m 'my_marker == "this"'`) does not work.

How can I do an "inverse selection", i.e. selecting all tests that are *not* marked with "that"?

And finally, what if the argument is not a string - maybe a bool or an int?

Answer (score 0):

Combining the `-m` and `-k` parameters together seems to do the trick

```
pytest -m "my_marker" -k "this"
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it works in my case (using pytest-7.2.1). Still says `collected 2 items / 2 deselected / 0 selected`. Even then, I couldn't filter using negative attributes (e.g. `-k "not this").

Comment: Both scenarios work for me on `7.2.1`

Comment: The question was about depending on the _marker argument_, not on the _test name_ as this does. It works accidentally for the example in the question because the tests also have the argument in the test name. And no, I don't have a solution short of writing a plugin for this, there is no possibility to do this with plain vanilla pytest to my knowledge, as the arguments are not part of the marker names.